# Explanation of Approximation for Integral Over Gaussian Distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I am reading an optics textbook that uses the following integral to evaluate the power squared in the lower tail of the following Gaussian integral.

$$\frac{1}{{{\sigma _P} \cdot \sqrt {2 \cdot \pi } }} \cdot \int\limits_{ - \infty }^0 {{P^2} \cdot \exp \left( { - \frac{{{{\left( {P - {P_b}} \right)}^2}}}{{2 \cdot \sigma _P^2}}} \right)}  \cdot dP
$$

The author gives the following approximation for the value of this integral with no explanation.
$$\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi }}  \cdot \frac{{\sigma _P^5}}{{P_b^3}} \cdot \exp \left( { - \frac{{P_b^2}}{{2 \cdot \sigma _P^2}}} \right)
$$

I have been unable to derive this approximation. Are any of you familiar with it?

Comment: Under what conditions is approximated the integral ?.

Comment: The only condition that I know of is that Pb is much larger than σp. In fact, the whole integral is much smaller than Pb. We are computing the "noise" caused by representing a signal that can go negative using optical power, which cannot be negative. This number must be small for low-noise transmission.